# Pandas - If cell is blank, turn a pd.timedelta[ns64] cell to a string '--'

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have been working on a python project to automate some reports my team was designing by hand.  I am running into a bit of an stubborn problem I can't figure out what I'm doing.

Essentially, the area I am stuck on has 4 separate data columns which I have made generic version of below.

```
Start Time | Finish Time | Not Usable Reason |  Start to Finish
   12:36       15:36                               3:00
   16:35       19:45        Production Defect      3:10
   19:55                    QA Failure
```

Not Usable Reason has at a high level two options.  Blank OR text describing the issue.  As well, depending on the issue, a finish time may not have been recorded due to some QA issue which was noticed before it was finished resulting in a Not Usable Reason which does not allow a start to finish to be calculated.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is IF there is a Not Usable Reason, in that row in the Start to Finish column, put a "--" into that field.

The code that I used to attempt this:

```
processor_df['Start to Finish'] = processor_df['Finish Time'] - processor_df['Start Time']

processor_df['Start to Finish'] = processor_df['Start to Finish'].astype(str)
processor_df['Start to Finish'] = processor_df.loc[pd.isnull(processor_df['Not Usable Reason']) == False, 'Start to Finish'] == '--'
processor_df['Start to Finish'] = pd.to_timedelta(processor_df['Start to Finish'])
```

This represents just a fraction of the code relating specifically to the small portion performing the calculation, then attempting to modify the start to finish column appropriately.

As well, I go from timedelta -> str -> timedelta due to an error I received when I didn't change it to a string:

```
ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed
```

The issue is my **desired** output would be:

```
Start Time | Finish Time | Not Usable Reason |  Start to Finish
   12:36       15:36                               3:00
   16:35       19:45        Production Defect       --
   19:55                    QA Failure              --
```

but the above code produces it as:

```
Start Time | Finish Time | Not Usable Reason |  Start to Finish
   12:36       15:36                               
   16:35       19:45        Production Defect      False
   19:55                    QA Failure             False
```

What is the best way to use a check if a condition exists and if it does replace it.  The above has worked when I used it purely for strings but my condition was not checking if it as blank, but if it matched a specific value.

Thank you for your help with this, and if its a stupidly simple mistake, I thank you twice as hard for helping a novice out.

Best,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is where I think the problem lies:

```
processor_df['Start to Finish'] = processor_df.loc[pd.isnull(processor_df['Not Usable Reason']) == False, 'Start to Finish'] == '--'
```

You are basically overwriting the `Start to Finish` column with a boolean array. Your last expression in the line of code is `==` which returns a boolean array of all `False` values because of course the string `'--'` is not in any of the cells of that column.

The following line should do the trick instead:

```
processor_df.loc[processor_df['Not Usable Reason'].notnull() , 'Start to Finish'] = '--'
```

We use `.loc`, which I would in general recommend to start using out of habit for indexing rather than just square brackets, to get the rows where we have a `'Not Usable Reason'` and the column `'Start to Finish'` and we assign (using `=`, the assignment operator) the string `'--'` to these cells.

Comment: Thank you for that! It worked perfectly.  I need to read up to better understand when somethign is considered to be a copy of a slice from a dataframe.  I will take a close reader of that on pandas website.  Thank you again!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!